# Convert a timestamp to int using astype(int)

Tags: python, pandas, timestamp, integer

I have the variable `time`:

```
>>> time = pd.to_datetime(1613260800000000000)
>>> time
Timestamp('2021-02-14 00:00:00')
```

`time` is a `timestamp`. Now I want to convert `time` back to an `int` value. But `Timestamp` object has no attribute `astype`. Running the following code:

```
>>>time.astype(int)

AttributeError: 'Timestamp' object has no attribute 'astype'
```

I know that for a column of a dataframe I can do:

```
>>> df['start_time'] = df['start_time'].to_timedate()
>>> df['start_time'] = df['start_time'].astype(int)
```

The second command assigns the type of the column to `int`.

But I did not find a comprehensive source explaining what to do with individual `Timestamp` argument.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Hi, may I know what is the expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `ns` like native format for `numpy/pandas` use:

```
d = pd.to_datetime(1613260800000000000)

native = int(d.timestamp() * 10**9)
print (native)
1613260800000000000

print (pd.to_datetime(native))
2021-02-14 00:00:00
```

If need convert column:

```
time = pd.to_datetime(1613260800000000000)

df = pd.DataFrame({'start_time':[time, time]})

print (df['start_time'].astype(np.int64))
0    1613260800000000000
1    1613260800000000000
Name: start_time, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 4):

just use `time_variable.timestamp()`

but that will be in seconds ... instead of ms or whatever (us?)

you will need to multiply the result by `1e9` to get back the same value as you put in

Comment: `time_variable.value` returns the timestamp as nanoseconds since the epoch (as the OPs input).